# Uncaught TypeError: someMethod is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, runtime-error, upgrade, chromium

Note: that this error happens on a fully functional product (production codebase).

This happened after upgrading Chrome to Version "119.0.6045.159".

I've also tried my code on Chromium too, after upgrading it to "121.0.6151.0"

EXAMPLE:

```js
...
// The Database class ctor definition:
RDatabase()
{
    const SCHEMA = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trajPnts(...);';
    ...
    const PRESTM = 'INSERT INTO trajPnts(x1,x2,x3,...) VALUES(?,?,?,...);';
    try
    {
        this.db = openDatabase(...);
        this.createSchema = function ()
        { 
            ...
        }
        this.insertData = function (traj)    // <--- THE "insertData" METHOD !!!
        {
            ...
        }
        this.createSchema();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        ...
    }

}
...
// Create a Database instance:
var dbr = new RDatabase();
// Register a handler to record incoming data:
Handler.RegisterTrajHandler(
    function(traj)
    {
        dbr.insertData(traj);
    }
);
...
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: insertData is not a function
```

Comment: This method is created in a `Database` class but later you create an instance of a different class called `RDatabase` - is that a typo?

Comment: Since you're only defining those methods within a `try`/`catch` block, presumably an exception occurs there and the method doesn't get defined. You might want to look at the exception `e` in that `catch(e)` block...

Comment: I removed the try{}catch{} blocks and it WON'T fail anywhere inside the ctor.
So you are wrong. Though, It would have poped up with one of the alert/debugging popups that i have inside the catch block (but i've tried removing the try/catch for you, to test it, and it didn't failed) !
NOTE that it started happening on a fully functional production code !
It keeps:
`"VM1294:106 Uncaught TypeError: dbr.insertData is not a function"`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you tried it without any try/catch that could swallow errors? Humor me and add `this.insertData = function() { console.log("toot!"); throw new Error(); };` before that `this.db = ` thing? That way you'd see `toot!` in the console if your code ended up using the "wrong" insertData.

Comment: If any Error or (Exception - in "Java terms") may have happened it would have been reported as unwinding at point "`var dbr = new RDatabase();`"
Thankfully i'm currently running my product on my laptop (since i've not ungraded the Chrome browser on my laptop yet) UNTIL i figure out what the heck they did on **Chrome/Chromium releases's Javascript Engine** !!!

Comment: I very much doubt this is a Chrome/Chromium JavaScript engine bug. Did you try what I suggested above? Also, have you tried using the debugger ("pause on uncaught exceptions") to see what the `dbr` object actually looks like at that point?

Comment: So what happened when you tried what I suggested? Did you get that "toot!"? Also, what did the debugger tell you about the object? Does it have an `insertData` member? (Or `createSchema`?) (EDIT: ah, seems a comment went missing from before this.)

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work because the feature has been removed per the announcements of the past 2 years?

Comment: @Yogi Ah, yep. I didn't even realize OP was using WebSQL. That indeed seems to have been deprecated in Chromium 119: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deprecating-web-sql/

Comment: Glad you found a solution. However I'm pretty curious as to why the `openDatabase  is not defined` exception supposedly never appeared for you when you tried to remove that try/catch, etc.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem comes from the Chrome team having removed the "already"
> deprecated the **Web SQL Database API**.
>
> It was an API internally based on the SQLite database engine, that was
> introduced in April 2009 and it was abandoned in November 2010.
>
> The Web SQL Database API has come to an end and got removed (finally)
> on the Chromium 119 release (on October 31, 2023).
>
> Meanwhile, the **World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)** encourages those
> needing web databases to adopt **Web Storage API** technologies like
> `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, or `IndexedDB` since the
> deprecation of this API.
>
> There is also a SQLite implementation over **WebAssembly** for all
> those who like do it the SQLite way.

<sup>Originally posted into the question by the OP. [Revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77555100/11)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Yogi in the comments, this is likely to do with the fact that the Web SQL standard [has been deprecated for a long while and is finally removed in Chromium 119](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/deprecating-web-sql/).

The issue is obscured by the `try/catch` in your original code; since `openDatabase` fails (presumably "openDatabase is not defined" or similar), the `this.createSchema` and `this.insertData` functions never get defined either:

```js
function RDatabase() {
  try {
    this.db = openDatabase();
    this.insertData = function(traj) {};
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}


var rdb = new RDatabase();
console.log(rdb.db);
console.log(rdb.insertData);
```

If you still need the SQLite API going forward, you will need to migrate to e.g. [this SQLite WebAssembly port](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sqlite-wasm-in-the-browser-backed-by-the-origin-private-file-system/) (linked in the aforementioned blog post as a recommendation by the Chrome team).